# Pain of animals on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

So a friend of mine showed me the following verse from Matthew 12:11 (strange to bring a New Testament quote into a halacha question, I know)

> ...  they asked him, “Is it lawful to heal on the Sabbath?”
>   11 He said to them, “If any of you has a sheep and it falls into a pit on the Sabbath, will you not take hold of it and lift it out?

He (my friend) asked me what was going on here. I understand the first bit about healing (I assume that this is a general reference to the prohibition against medicine due to grinding), but the second part is strange. It seems from here that the prushim agreed that lifting a sheep out and helping it is not a problem.

I am rather confused by this. Does it mean that there was an eruv or similar, and that one really is allowed to do quite a bit to ease the pain of animals on shabbat (the only exception that I had heard of before this was milking dairy cows)? Or is there something else that is going on in this quote?

**Note:** I believe that the people that were being spoken to here were the prushim (Pharisees), who I believe had the right mesora and everything, and from whom Jews today come.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26977/is-it-ever-permissible-to-break-shabbos-in-order-to-relieve-someone-of-suffering and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26976/is-it-permissible-to-be-mechalel-shabbos-to-save-the-life-of-an-animal-or-pet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.dinonline.org/2011/09/13/cruelty-to-animals-halachos-of-tzaar-baalei-chayim/

> Elsewhere, however (Shabbos 128b), with regard to the laws of muktzeh
>   on Shabbos, the Gemara states that the prohibition is a Torah law.
>   Where an animal has fallen into a pit, and cannot be fed, one may
>   assist it to ascend by placing cushions under it. Although this
>   involves a rabbinic prohibition (of ‘annulling’ the cushions—they
>   become muktzeh), it is permitted on account of the pain experienced by
>   the animal.
>
> It is important to point out that the Torah prohibition of causing
>   animals to suffer does not apply for all degrees of pain. The Nimmukei
>   Yosef (Bava Metzia, loc. cit.) writes that the prohibition applies to
>   “great distress,” but not to “slight distress.”
>
> The example he brings is of an animal that fell into a pit on Shabbos.
>   Although the animal surely experiences certain discomfort in being
>   stuck in a pit, it is only permitted to help the animal out (in
>   transgression of a branch of the rabbinic muktzeh prohibition) if the
>   animal cannot be fed in the pit.
>
> Where it is possible to cater for the animal’s needs in the pit, the
>   discomfort of being stuck in the pit will not be sufficient cause to
>   defer the rabbinic prohibition.