# Is it permissible to be mechalel Shabbos to save the life of an animal or pet?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Is it permissible to be mechalel Shabbos to save the life of an animal, such as a family pet?
Could minchag, chumras, and/or purely Rabbinical prohibitions be relaxed in such a situation, and to what extent?

Please assume no Gentile is available to save the animal's life. However, if it would be permissible to relax certain rules in order to summon a Gentile for this purpose, please discuss.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/pain-of-animals-on-shabbat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Mishna Brurah 332:6 it is assur to violate a Torah or Rabbinic law to save an animals life but one can ask a אינו יהודי . However to heal it in a certain way see Mishna Brurah 332:5,9 .

Comment: If dying would cause it pain, couldn't Tzar Baalei Chayim be a factor? We permit at least some Rabbinic laws to that end (eg. milking cows in certain ways).

Comment: @DoubleAA ,That's the Mishna Brurah 9.However,it seems assur generally.The heter seems to come from בהול .

Comment: +1. I have a crazy family story about this; in short, someone asked my father (a people doctor) about a rabbit whose life was in danger....we asked the rabbi, who said to ask a non-Jew to take it to the veterinary hospital. (the rabbit, unfortunately, didn't make it)